# Which Django version should i use for production?

Tags: django

I want to start new project in Django, but i am confused which I should be using?

I Also want to know which Django version is popular and used in industry.

Answer (score 4):

The latest stable version, which as of today is Django 1.7.4.

This page indicates which version is the most recent: https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Note that [certain Django version are tagged as "LTS"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/internals/release-process/#long-term-support-lts-releases), and receive support for three years. The current LTS is 1.4, which is already quite old. Sticking to 1.8 when it ships will be a viable option though (1.8 will be a LTS).